# How does a seagull changes from floating almost stationary against the wind to high speed after turning 180 degrees?

Tags: flow, aerodynamics

I think we all know the sight of seagulls almost floating stationary when they get the wind full on. And I think we also all have seen that when he knows behind him he (she) there is food, he turns 180 degrees and gets a high boost in speed in a short time.

Of course, this is because when he's floating his wings are formed in a way to catch a lot of air from the front, allowing him to flow, while when he turns and gets this velocity boost his wings form in a way to get as much as wind from the back to give him this boost.

I've observed that when they float they make their wings as broad as possible, while when they need the speed boost their wingspan is much smaller.

Are my observations correct? And if so what forms the wings have (approximately) in both cases?

Comment: is the speed bust because they are falling faster?

Comment: Please use a high altitude drone and paint it like a fish, we can check the streaming live on youtube to confirm your observation

Comment: They fly relative to the air, not the ground. Suppose they fly at 30 mph, and the wind is 30 mph. If they are flying against the wind, their groundspeed will be 0. If they are flying with the wind their groundspeed will be 60.

Answer (score -1):

No bird or flying object can fly level or climb, taking advantage of opposing wind and not sink.

Birds and glider planes and any flying object enjoy lift riding thermals, but both birds and gliders are always descending in the surrounding air with what can optimally be their glide slope, which is the least angle of descent that is a property of the particular geometry, drag, mass, altitude, temperature.

What you are observing possibly may be a bird that has been flying fast into the wind by flapping, or just took of from a branch and dove down to accelerate for, coasting into the wind. While the wind is slowing it down it has a different speed (call it the speed the bird or wing feels, relative speed).

This relative speed will affect lift exactly as the speed caused by thrust of the engine or flapping the wings by the bird in calm weather.

However this difference in speed will burn out by the drag soon, and the bird or plane will fly at the ambiant wind speed and will sink.

That is the reason in airplane instrument panel the wind speed instrument is always measuring the relative wings' wind speed not the absolute airplane's ground speed.

And many crashes have happened because of faulty pitot tube which measure the relative wing wind speed off reading the wings wind stagnation pressure on a drum at the end of a tube opening at the front of the wing.

Because if the plane is being pushed by say a 200 miles wind forward but is moving with the same speed ground speed it will sink and stall. It must fly with say 350 miles ground speed so that the 150 miles relative speed give it lift and not to fall off the sky.

Same logic applies to when the bird turns and flies with the wind. It will descend if it doesn't flap, even though it's land speed may be fast.